# Should I go to upper management to use a solution that my immediate supervisor doesn't like?

Tags: management

We have been unable to satisfy one of the requirements for a project. In discussing this with a friend (same industry, outside the company, not a competing situation), we came up with an idea which seems promising.  Some effort will be required to test it out, and - if it proves workable - make it work and put it into place.

My expectation was that my boss would be pleased with this idea and tell me to proceed with the initial testing.  Instead she rejected it and told me that I am not to spend time working on it. Her initial rejection of my idea was a few weeks ago.  I've brought it up a couple more times, but have gotten the same response.  She has an idea that involves a third party, which has been unresponsive to my boss' communications efforts; nonetheless, she continues saying this is how we'll proceed. This incident has left me with the impression that she is only interested in pursuing ideas she comes up with.

We're getting fairly deep into the project; we're on schedule, but if we don't come up with a solution to this requirement soon, there's a possibility that we'll miss our deadline for completion. I don't want our project to fail because of this issue. Should I go up the management chain to try to get permission to try this out?  Or should I just wait and hope she changes her mind? Or just let it be and figure that if we fail it's her responsibility? Or is there another approach I've not thought of?

Comment: What is *her* solution for the requirement problem?  Does she have one and it doesn't work, or does she not have one and she's making that your problem (but your idea isn't acceptable to her)?

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Thanks to the feedback.  I've updated the question to explain her idea.

Comment: has she explained *why* yours is a bad idea. if not have you asked?

Comment: @RhysW: When I asked why she doesn't want to use my solution, her response was a vague "We don't want to go that way" (or similar). Thus my statement that she's not interested in ideas that weren't hers originally.

Comment: The question cited as a duplicate is asking how to go about going over the boss' head.  This question is asking whether it's a good idea to do so (and also about alternatives too doing so).

Comment: Do you know *all* circumstances around your project ? Do you see *all* of the big picture ? A lot of organizations will involve third parties for numerous reasons, IMHO, shifting performance responsibility is one.

Comment: Voted to reopen as I don't feel the duplicate actually answers the question.

Comment: @happybuddha: The project is pretty small (3 people working on it), and the 3rd party would just be providing something they already have.

Answer (score 17):

Going up the management chain to override your supervisor in this instance is a really bad idea.

I've been there and aside from the fact that upper management don't want to be micro-managing projects, it's also going to kill your relationship with your existing boss who probably has significant influence in your career right now.

Put it to one side, work on the work you need to do and if/when the requirement becomes a blocker - listen to the other suggestions people come up with and then, and only then, bring up your solution again so it can be objectively assessed against all the other options.